# Normalize FIX logs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fix-protocol

I have a log file (FIX) that I'm trying to convert to csv with headers for example:

```
8=FIX.4.2|9=435|35=8|34=8766|49=SENDERCOMPID|50=ET1|52=20230228-14:31:17.796|56=TARGETCOMPID|
8=FIX.4.2|9=435|35=8|34=8767|49=SENDERCOMPID|50=ET1|52=20230228-14:31:17.796|56=TARGETCOMPID|
8=FIX.4.2|9=435|35=8|34=8768|49=SENDERCOMPID|50=ET1|52=20230228-14:31:17.796|56=TARGETCOMPID|
```

Looking to normalize into a csv as follows:

```
8,9,35,34,49,50,52,56
FIX.4.2,435,8,8766,SENDERCOMPID,ET1,20230228-14:31:17.796,TARGETCOMPID
FIX.4.2,435,8,8767,SENDERCOMPID,ET1,20230228-14:31:17.796,TARGETCOMPID
FIX.4.2,435,8,8768,SENDERCOMPID,ET1,20230228-14:31:17.796,TARGETCOMPID
```

Reading the file log:

```py
with open(some.txt) as file:
        data = file.read()

fix = pd.read_csv(data,sep='|')
print(fix)
```

I have some regex for the headers and parsing the data:

```py
# regexforheader = re.compile("(?<=\|)(.*?)(?==)")
# regexRowData = re.compile="(?<=\=)(.*?)(?=\|)"
```

Stumped how to put it all together.

edit1: throws an error when new field is introduced:

```py
8=FIX.4.2|9=435|35=8|34=8766|49=SENDERCOMPID|50=ET1|52=20230228-14:31:17.796|56=TARGETCOMPID|
8=FIX.4.2|9=435|35=8|34=8767|49=SENDERCOMPID|50=ET1|52=20230228-14:31:17.796|56=TARGETCOMPID|
8=FIX.4.2|9=435|35=8|34=8768|49=SENDERCOMPID|50=ET1|52=20230228-14:31:17.796|56=TARGETCOMPID|
8=FIX.4.2|9=435|35=8|34=8768|49=SENDERCOMPID|50=ET1|52=20230228-14:31:17.796|56=TARGETCOMPID|109=test|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas), you can use [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and a [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv('in.csv', sep='|', header=None)

(df.stack().str.split('=', n=1, expand=True)
   .droplevel(1).pivot(columns=0, values=1)
   .sort_index(axis=1, key=lambda x: x.astype(int))
   .to_csv('out.csv', index=False)
)
```

Using the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module (and assuming the first line defines all the columns):

```
import re
import csv

with open('in.csv') as f_in, open('out.csv', 'w') as f_out:
    first = True
    for l in csv.reader(f_in, delimiter='|'):
        d = dict(x.split('=') for x in l if x)
        if first:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(f_out, d.keys(), delimiter=',')
            writer.writeheader()
            first = False
        writer.writerow(d)
```

Output:

```
8,9,34,35,49,50,52,56
FIX.4.2,435,8766,8,SENDERCOMPID,ET1,20230228-14:31:17.796,TARGETCOMPID
FIX.4.2,435,8767,8,SENDERCOMPID,ET1,20230228-14:31:17.796,TARGETCOMPID
FIX.4.2,435,8768,8,SENDERCOMPID,ET1,20230228-14:31:17.796,TARGETCOMPID
```

##### timings

on 300k rows of input:

```
# pandas version
3.36 s ± 119 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# csv version
1.61 s ± 35.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: I used the df solution and works well.  My actual dataset has variable column length, so I suppose I would need to format so that all Columns are accounted for as the first entry?  

The column headers I am looking to map from the actual fix field name, like so :

BeginString(8), BodyLength(9) etc. taken from : https://www.onixs.biz/fix-dictionary/4.2/fields_by_name.html

Comment: @fixguy23 I'm not sure I got your remark. My pandas solution doesn't require the fields to be identical in all rows, you can mix and match. Give is a try and let me know if you have a specific issue (provide an example) ;)

Comment: see my edit1, when I introduce a new tag in the last row :
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 9 fields in line 4, saw 10

Comment: This means that you made an invalid CSV(-like) file by adding a value that doesn't have a matching header

Comment: Right, my csv may have rows that dont fit the first rows' headers.  At that point I just have to make sure row with the most headers is first, but was looking for simple way to ensure the row with the most columns gets printed first.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`pandas.Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) and [`pandas.Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html)

```py
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd


file = """8=FIX.4.2|9=435|35=8|34=8766|49=SENDERCOMPID|50=ET1|52=20230228-14:31:17.796|56=TARGETCOMPID|
8=FIX.4.2|9=435|35=8|34=8767|49=SENDERCOMPID|50=ET1|52=20230228-14:31:17.796|56=TARGETCOMPID|
8=FIX.4.2|9=435|35=8|34=8768|49=SENDERCOMPID|50=ET1|52=20230228-14:31:17.796|56=TARGETCOMPID|"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(file), sep="|", header=None)

# drop all nan column
df = df.dropna(axis="columns", how="all")

df.columns = df.apply(lambda ser: ser.str.extract("(\d+)", expand=False)).drop_duplicates().iloc[0]

df = df.apply(lambda ser: ser.str.split("=").str[-1])

df.to_csv("out.csv", index=False)
```

```
8,9,35,34,49,50,52,56
FIX.4.2,435,8,8766,SENDERCOMPID,ET1,20230228-14:31:17.796,TARGETCOMPID
FIX.4.2,435,8,8767,SENDERCOMPID,ET1,20230228-14:31:17.796,TARGETCOMPID
FIX.4.2,435,8,8768,SENDERCOMPID,ET1,20230228-14:31:17.796,TARGETCOMPID
```

Comment: Note that this assumes that all fields are always in the same order, if not this will mix them up in the output ;)